# Leaftlet Circlemarker Color

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

Hi I was wondering how I would go about changing react leaflet circle marker colors based on unique IDs.

right now my circle markers look like this:

```
         <CircleMarker
            key={index}
            center={[value?.Latitude, value?.Longitude]}
            radius={15}
            color="pink"
          >
```

and I have an ID value being passed with my Lats and Longs.

```
value: {
                Latitude: number
                Longitude: number
                ID: string
              },
```

Don't know if it's helpful, but In R there was a pal feature where I could do something like

```
pal <- colorFactor(rainbow(4), domain = unique(tmp$ID), levels = unique(tmp$ID))
```

and then pass it as an option

```
clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions(), color = pal(tmp$ID))
```

I'm not sure how to do this in React.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Data is based on a query but this is basically it's format:

```
const data = [
    {
      Latitude: 0,
      Longitude: 0,
      ID: '206520',
    },
    {
        Latitude: 10,
        Longitude: 10,
        ID: '206520',
    },    
    {
        Latitude: 1,
        Longitude: 1,
        ID: '200000',
      },    {
        Latitude: 1,
        Longitude: 1,
        ID: '300400500',
      },
    ]
```

If the ID is the same, they should return the same color.
So for example mappings with 206520 should both be the same color.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Will you always have a unique id being passed along with the coordinates? Also provide an explanation for this " I'd like to check for unique values and then assign the unique 'groups' (for example 1 and 1 ) the same colors." It is not clear at least to me. Also you should include this in your question

Comment: Hi  @kboul, Yes there is always an ID passed with the Coordinates. However they aren't always unique. Sometimes the ID can repeat because they represent a group. 

What I meant by my statement was if I had a list of IDs and two of them were equal to '1' I'd like them to be the same color.  But if an ID was equal to '2' Id like it to be a different color. 
Maybe ID is just a bad term and I should change it to something like Groups. 
Thanks for your help last time aswell!

Comment: Welcome. If you have always an ID assigned to each circle marker regardless of its value you can assign a predefined color. It will only take a function to return the right one based on the ID.  If that is the case it sounds simple and doable. Maybe if you provide a demo to demonstrate your case it would be easier to understand the exact case

Comment: @kboul I've added some data to the question, but if there's anything else I could provide to help you understand what I'm going for, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it with the help of kbouls comments and answer.

First you create an array of unique/ distinct numbers based on the ID field. For me it's a distinct query, but it could just be a function where you push all elements to a list and remove duplicates. Either way let's call it UniqueList.

Next you create a list of the colors you would like.

```
//can be the word 'red' or the code '#ef4444'
    const colors = [
      '#ef4444',
      '#d97706',
      '#0284c7',
      '#d946ef',
    ]
```

Now that there are two lists, you can tie them together

```
  const ColorMatched = {}

  uniqueList.forEach((element, index) => {
    ColorMatched[element] = colors[index]
  })
```

You should an output like `{206520 : '#ef4444' } //ect`

Now kbouls code can be implemented with

```
const getColor = (ID) => {
  return colorIds[ID];
};
```

and

```
  <CircleMarker
    key={index}
    center={[value?.Latitude, value?.Longitude]}
    radius={15}
    color={getColor(value.ID)}
  />
```

As value.ID calls back the corresponding color. E.g `Color = {'#ef4444'}`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
<CircleMarker
        key={index}
        center={[value?.Latitude, value?.Longitude]}
        radius={15}
        color={value?.color}
>
```

And add a color property to the value object.
Then, when initialising each value object, add it’s unique color.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think this isn't what I'm looking for. You don't know the ID value before hand  to assign them. I'd like to check for unique values and then assign the unique 'groups' (for example 1 and 1 ) the same colors. There could also be a large amount of differing IDs

Answer (score 0):

You can define an associative array in JS with keys the IDs (you should know the IDs in advance but you don't care where they are assigned) and values the colors you want the circles to have. After that create a simple function where you will pass the value.ID and you would return the dictionary's value like this:

```
const colorIds = {
  206520: "yellow",
  300400500: "red",
  200000: "green"
};

const getColor = (ID) => {
  return colorIds[ID];
};
```

Inside the component

```
{data.map((value, index) => {
        if (!value?.Latitude || !value?.Longitude) return null;
        return (
          <CircleMarker
            key={index}
            center={[value?.Latitude, value?.Longitude]}
            radius={15}
            color={getColor(value.ID)}
          />
        );
 })}
```

this is what I understood from your description. Let me know anyways if it is close to what you are looking for.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaftlet-v-4-x-circlemarker-color-6vw4cr)

Comment: Thank you for all your time and help with this. This is close to what I'm looking for, except you don't know the values of those IDs beforehand.

The background of the code  is that someone uploads a sheet containing data to a database, The database is queried for these specific rows, mapped based on it's coordinates and  markers are color coordinated based on it's ID.

Comment: You re welcome. Then is more tricky. As you won't have any condition or criteria to assign a color. How will you plan to do it then? I am not sure, that is how I assumed you some information like this

Comment: Yes, this is what I had the problem with.  In R there was a 'unique' attribute which was able to group them. Maybe I'll have to query a unique list and then a for statement that assigns a color based on this list?

Comment: Actually the assignment of the color should be performed on the backend based on what you write. In my opinion it makes no sense to do it in the front. I am not familiar with R therefore I cannot compare the approach there. But anyways all the info in your comments should be included in the first place in the question description as it makes easier for a potential responder to take into account all this special info and give a more suitable answer to your requirements!

Comment: thank you again for your time. I ended up solving it with your helpful comments